# MVVMCross Tab Navigation with Backstack

Tags: android, tabs, mvvmcross

Is there currently a way to do the tabbed navigation in MVVMCross like as a example the YouTube App, which has a sub navigation for each tab or is this something which has to be implemented by myself? How would be a clean way to do so then? Should i adjust the Presenter?

A example:
I have three tabs, where i can navigate from one to another. If i select a element in the first tab, it navigates to a new ViewModel and replaces the first tab, while i still can switch to the other tabs. If i navigate back in the first tab, i get back to the old first tab.

Comment: did you found an easy solution?

Comment: Not really. Basically have to handle it yourself, so it was put on hold for now due to the amount of work needed.

Comment: I've managed to make it work easily.

Comment: Would you mind to share your solution?

Answer (score 3):

Solution architecture:

```
Activity  
  TabLayout  
  ViewPager  
     RootFragment (1 per tab, created/deleted by the viewpager depdending of the selected tab)
         |-- ChildFragmentManager of the RootFragment (= independant navigation stack)
         | Tab1Fragment1  
         | Tab1Fragment2  
         | Tab1Fragment3
```

- The main view is an mvvmcross activity "HomeContainerActivity"
- For the tab buttons, i used a TabLayout.
- The content is a ViewPager linked to the tablayout. The viewpager switches the displayed fragment when a tab is selected.
- The ViewPager's adapter is fed with a custom MvxCachingFragmentPagerAdapter which instantiates a RootTabFragment instead of the fragment specified MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo and initialize it with the fragment which will be the root of the stack
- The RootTabFragment's layout has only one content where the above fragment is placed.

That's all. Navigating to a viewmodel opens it in the current top fragment. This means standard navigation will work as expected, back button needs a little code in your main activity though. Also you can't change tab by code without a custom view presenter.

Main activity layout:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/chrome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <!-- fragment content for popups -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentPopup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="5dp"/>

    <!-- action/tool bar -->
    <!-- must be below all contents -->
    <include layout="@layout/activity_home_toolbar" />

    <!-- tab bar -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                app:tabIndicator="@null"
                />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ViewPager setup with TabLayout:

```
            var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo>
            {
                new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Tab1", typeof(Tab1Fragment).FragmentJavaName(), typeof(Tab1Fragment), typeof(Tab1ViewModel)),
                new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Tab2", typeof(Tab2Fragment).FragmentJavaName(), typeof(Tab2Fragment), typeof(Tab2ViewModel)),
            };

            viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
            viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter2(this, SupportFragmentManager, fragments);

            tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Custom fragment pager adapter:

```cs
    [Register("vapolia.MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter2")]
    public class MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter2 : MvxCachingFragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly Context context;

        [Preserve(Conditional=true)]
        protected MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter2(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) {}

        public MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter2(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo> fragmentsInfo) : base(fragmentManager)
        {
            this.context = context;
            FragmentsInfo = fragmentsInfo;
        }

        public override int Count => FragmentsInfo?.Count() ?? 0;
        public List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo> FragmentsInfo { get; }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position, Fragment.SavedState fragmentSavedState = null)
        {
            var fragment = (RootTabFragment)Fragment.Instantiate(context, typeof(RootTabFragment).FragmentJavaName());
            fragment.FragmentInfo = FragmentsInfo[position];
            return fragment;
        }

        public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object @object) => PagerAdapter.PositionNone;
        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position) => new Java.Lang.String(FragmentsInfo.ElementAt(position).Title);
        protected override string GetTag(int position) => FragmentsInfo[position].Tag;
        public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object objectValue) {} //Disable destroy
    }
```

Root tab fragment:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Special fragment used as the root content for every tab items.
    /// This enables a specific navigation stack for each tab item (using ChildFragmentManager).
    /// 
    /// Contains only one subfragment
    /// </summary>
    public class RootTabFragment : Fragment
    {
        public MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo FragmentInfo { get; set; }

        [Android.Runtime.Preserve(Conditional=true)]
        protected RootTabFragment(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) {}

        [Android.Runtime.Preserve(Conditional=true)]
        public RootTabFragment()
        {
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.home_common_root, container, false);
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            var fm = ChildFragmentManager;

            var isCacheable = FragmentInfo.FragmentType.IsFragmentCacheable(Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity.GetType());
            var firstFragment = fm.FindFragmentByTag(FragmentInfo.Tag) ?? Fragment.Instantiate(Context, FragmentInfo.FragmentType.FragmentJavaName());

            // ReSharper disable once SuspiciousTypeConversion.Global
            if (firstFragment is IMvxFragmentView mvxFragment)
            {
                if (savedInstanceState == null || !isCacheable)
                {
                    var viewModel = FragmentInfo.ViewModel ?? CreateViewModel();
                    mvxFragment.ViewModel = viewModel;
                }
            }

            var ft = fm.BeginTransaction();
            ft.SetReorderingAllowed(true);
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content, firstFragment, FragmentInfo.Tag);
            ft.CommitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

        private IMvxViewModel CreateViewModel()
        {
            MvxBundle mvxBundle = null;
            if (FragmentInfo.ParameterValuesObject != null)
                mvxBundle = new MvxBundle(FragmentInfo.ParameterValuesObject.ToSimplePropertyDictionary());
            var request = new MvxViewModelRequest(FragmentInfo.ViewModelType, mvxBundle, null);

            return Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>().LoadViewModel(request, null);
        }
    }
```

Root tab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <!-- fragment content for navigation -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

A sample fragment which will go into a root tab fragment:

```
    [MvxFragmentPresentation(FragmentContentId = Resource.Id.content, AddToBackStack = false, ActivityHostViewModelType = typeof(HomeContainerActivity), IsCacheableFragment = true)]
    public class SettingsFragment : BaseFragment<SettingsViewModel>, IFragmentWithTitle
    {
        protected override int FragmentLayoutId => Resource.Layout.home_settings;
        public string TitleText => "Settings";
    }
```

Fixed onbackpressed in activity:

```
        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            var n = SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount;
            if (n >= 1)
            {
                base.OnBackPressed();
            }
            else
            {
                //Try to use the current selected tab's backstack
                var currentFragment = (Fragment)viewPager.Adapter.InstantiateItem(null, viewPager.CurrentItem); //Returns the existing fragment
                var fm = currentFragment.ChildFragmentManager;
                n = fm.BackStackEntryCount;
                if (n >= 1)
                {
                    //Must use immediate, so SetCorrectTitle can use the updated backstack to set the correct title
                    fm.PopBackStackImmediate();

                    if (n == 1)
                        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); //Set to true to display back button

                    //SetCorrectTitle();
                }
                else
                {
                    base.OnBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Looks interesting so far. Would it work if you would leave the TabView and go to other Views which are added to the backstack till you navigate back to the TabView?

Comment: Yes it works. I've updated my own code to remove the dependency on the ViewPager and simplified and fix further things too. But the base architecture is the same.